# best way to store list of blobs with corresponding points

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist, blob

What’s the best way to store blobs detected in an image together with their corresponding pixels (points)?

List of Lists? ArrayList?

This is what I‘d like to end up with:
Blobs[0] ....  Blobs[x]
and for each one of them I‘d like to be able to retrieve all points found in the individual blob (a list of points within each blob).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: regarding the choice of a suitable variable I haven’t tried anything so far, because I couldn’t find any useful information on mixed datatype list of lists. I assume it would be best to have an int list (for the blobs) containing lists of points (for all pixels that belong to the individual blobs) - but how to achieve that?